# How can i automate my computer?

Tags: automation, filenames

On windows 10.

I need to automate the repeated process of these steps.
1. Open up an image in GIMP. Scale it to 110%. 
2. Export as somefile name(for example input001.jpg).
3. Go to http://deepdreamgenerator.com/ in a browser. click on button, browse to the exported file.
4. Wait for it to generate result, save image as result file (for example dream001.jpg).
then repeat from step 1 with the result file from step 4...but keep increasing the filename number so export it as input002.jpg...
What software would allow me to do this?

Comment: That comment is not at all helpful.

Comment: Not enough information for one thing. What OS? You may want to look into ImageMagik and curl, though for automating this stuff.

Comment: no that comment is not helpful at all. and who gave me a -1 on my question it is a real question that begs for a suggestion of a possible tool for automation.  I can automate things in GIMP with scheme..but i don't know of any tool that will automate the process of manual labor of user clicking things and waiti

Comment: I think the -1 are essentially due to your question's wording.
'automating a computer" doesn't have much sense.

What you need to automate is a repetitive manual task, which seems complex to put in a "macro" or "batch file", since you use gimp and a web tool, and have to deal with problems like waiting for the image to generate before continuing.
Just iterating over images for a single treatment would be quite easy.

Btw, have you considered looking for tools usable in batches (e.g. for upscaling your image.  maybe Gimp can be called that way, which would be *way* easier than emulating clicks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried AutoHotKey but didn't feel like learning a whole new scripting language so I found something simpler called **GhostMouse**.
It just has record,play,stop buttons.
after recording and closing out of program it asks if i want to save script. clicked yes gave it a name, and then edited the script file..and copied and pasted as many times as i wanted the script to run (before copying and pasting i deleted the last 3 lines which has to do with clicking the stop button which i didn't want the script to do).

Answer (score 1):

the only software i know of that * **MIGHT** * be able to automate that process is [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com)

You would need to keep the windows which you're automating static (ie. make sure they don't move) and then write keyboard and mouse macros in autohotkey to press the buttons and do the things you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Sikuli for same. It's an image comparator

```
 http://www.sikuli.org/
```

Reference :-

```
http://doc.sikuli.org/tutorials/
```